# How to create function 'Quit'?

Tags: python, pygame

I understood that if you press button 'Cross', you can't use `pygame.quit()`, otherwise program won't be able to work. So how to create 'Quit' by pressing the buttons `Sure`, `QUIT'?

```
def beginning():
    Beginning = True
    while Beginning:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                Beginning = False
        #[...]
        print_text_5('Welcome to my game!', 300, 50)
        mini_button.draw(570, 200, 'PLAY', game)
        mini_button.draw(570, 420, 'QUIT', #[???])
        pygame.display.update()

def game(): 
    Game = True
    while Game:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get(): 
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                beginning = False
            #[...]


        if health <= 0:
            game_over()
                
def game_over():
    Game_over = True
    while Game_over:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                game_over = False

        print_text_3('Do not worry! Better luck next time!', 360, 400)
        button.draw(600, 500, 'Sure!', #[???])
        pygame.display.update()

beginning()
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: `otherwise program won't be able to work` What do you mean? What won't be able to work about it? By "cross" do you mean the "X" button? If you press the X button, an event of the type `pygame.QUIT` will be raised; meaning that your `if event.type == pygame.QUIT:` statements will catch that event and then do something. Running `pygame.quit()` will close the game entirely. Is that not what you want to do? What do you want your custom `quit` function to do differently?

Comment: Why do you not follow my advice? [How to restart the game using the button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70350824/how-to-restart-the-game-using-the-button). There is no clean way of doing this with your approach.

Comment: I'm so sorry. I just didn't see notification which you answered on my question. It's really weird

Comment: @Vildan what error?

Comment: Too late. 1 answer has already helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class with a class variable `quit` and a static method `set_quit`:

```py
class QuitState:
    quit = False
    def set_quit():
        QuitState.quit = True
```

Pass the class method to the button. Ent the application loop when `QuitState.quit` is set:

```py
def beginning():
    Beginning = True
    while Beginning and not QuitState.quit:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                QuitState.set_quit() 
        #[...]
        print_text_5('Welcome to my game!', 300, 50)
        mini_button.draw(570, 200, 'PLAY', game)
        mini_button.draw(570, 420, 'QUIT', QuitState.set_quit)
        pygame.display.update()
```

```py
def game(): 
    while not QuitState.quit:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get(): 
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                QuitState.set_quit() 
           #[...]

        if health <= 0:
            game_over()
```

```py
def game_over():
    while QuitState.quit:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                QuitState.set_quit()

        print_text_3('Do not worry! Better luck next time!', 360, 400)
        button.draw(600, 500, 'Sure!', QuitState.set_quit)
        pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
import pygame
from sys import exit as sys_exit


def quit_game():
    pygame.quit()
    sys_exit()
```

Comment: Your method wasn't helped me, however thanks!